# What are the possible effects of upgrading to IIS Application Pool ASP.NET V4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, application-pool

Locally, I have upgraded my application to IIS Application Pool ASP.NET V4.0 Classic. The problem here is when I am planning to deploy it to our server I found out that there is an existing application running on Application Pool ASP.NET V2.0 Classic.

What are the possible effect to the existing application if I upgrade the server to Application Pool ASP.NET V4.0?

Comment: Hey, this seems like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie here. I have no account on programmers.stackexchange.com. Can you help me?

Comment: No worries :) Just login there, and you can login with GMail, Facebook, or your current StackOverflow account :)

Comment: At least you will hit breaking changes documented in this article, http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful link. Now I have to review the 1st app for some changes. Is it possible that you have different .NET version for two apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reponse should be... none... just do the regiis for .net 4.0 (if not done it allready) and create a new pool for your new application. Everything should go just fine!

Comment: Thank you for answering. Let me try it first